# Understating a very minimal GNU makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to edit a makefile, I have built my own before but I'm struggling to understand this very minimal example, which clearly uses conventions that I am not aware of. I've checked the GNU documentation but I'm not quite sure what to search for.

The makefile defines `SRCS` `OBJS` `LIBS` `CC` `CFLAGS`

The makefile then compiles the libraries without being told specifically how. e.g. line in file is:

```
mgrid.o: array_alloc.h timer.h
```

But the makefile actually executes:

```
gcc -std=c89 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic   -c -o mgrid.o mgrid.c
```

Could anybody help explain what is going on here? And where I can find information on how these standards are defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make` has certain default rules

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

is the general default rule.

```
mgrid.o: array_alloc.h timer.h
```

only tells that `mgrid.o` is also dependent on `array_alloc.h timer.h`

Answer (score 1):

> mgrid.o: array_alloc.h timer.h

means "I want to compile mgrid.o only if array_alloc.h timer.h have been changed."
You do not indicate which rule must be applied, so make will take his dafault rule for .o files which is the line given by Sergey L. :

> $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

When make sees a .o file, it looks for a .c file with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

In your makefile, you set the dependencies of `mgrid.o` to be `array_alloc.h` and `timer.h`.

The makefile checks if the following files exist:

```
array_alloc.h timer.h
```

Since it does, it then proceeds to compile `mgrid.c` to `mgrid.o`.

There's a good manual at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Answer (score 0):

As Sergey L. said, it tells that mgrid is dependent on these two files,
that means:
checks if the files exist,
checks if they where modified after mgrid.o has been compiled : if so, recompile it.